# Prove that $(a,b)\times(c,d)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Prove that
$$\forall x\in (a,b)\times(c,d)\subset\mathbb{R}^2,\; \exists \varepsilon>0,\; B(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq (a,b)\times (c,d)$$
where $\displaystyle B(x,\varepsilon)=\{v\in \mathbb{R}^2: \|v - x\|<\varepsilon \}$.

---

**My attempt:**
*Let $x=(x_1,x_2)\in (a,b)\times (c,d)$. So $a<x_1<b\land c<x_2<d$.*

[image: A picture of a plane with the rectangle (a,b)x(c,d), a point in it and a ball centered at that point]

*Figure suggests that the radius of the open ball (blue) ought be smaller than any of the green lines (or equal to the shortest one).

Let $\displaystyle\varepsilon =\min\{\|(x_1,d)-x\|,\|(x_1,c)-x\|,\|(a,x_2)-x\|,\|(b,x_2)-x\|\}=\|\alpha-x\|$.

And let $v\in B(x,\varepsilon)$, that is
$$\|v-x\|<\|\alpha-x\|.\tag{*}$$*

I can't find a way to prove that $(*)$ implies $v\in (a,b)\times (c,d)$.

How could I continue the proof? If I'm not going in the right direction a hint would also help.

Comment: If $v$ weren't in $(a,b)\times(c,d)$, then at least one of its coordinates would be further than $\varepsilon$ removed from the corresponding coordinate of $x$. Then use the triangle inequality to show that this would imply $\Vert x-v\Vert>\varepsilon$.

Comment: Is the exercise about $V$ or about $\Bbb R^2$, and if the latter, what norm exactly are you considering on $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, with respect to the vector space, I have corrected the question, thanks for noticing. In regards with the norm, it isn't specified in the problem what norm exactly, all the information given is that it is a norm satisfying, of course, all the properties of a norm.

Comment: @RandomUser but what is it’s formula? There are several definitions of norms on the plane

Comment: No formula is given, the idea is, as I understand it, to prove that if $\| \cdot\|$ is a norm of $\mathbb{R}^2$ then it satisfies the proposition. All we know is that $\displaystyle [\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^2,\; \|x\|=0\iff x=0]\; \land \; [\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^2, \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R},\; \|\lambda x\|=|\lambda| \|x\|] \; \land \; [\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2\; \|x+y\|\leq \|x\| +\|y\|]$.
This being the definition of a norm.